# Nosql Mongodb: How to order rows after performing mathematical operation on the columns

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have these documents

```
[
  {
    "_id": "59b804e1ee8a4071a5ea3fcc",
    "x": 10.5,
    "y": 2.1,
    "z": 3.2
  },
  {
    "_id": "59b804e1ee8a4071a5ea2gzz",
    "x": 8.2,
    "y": 5.1,
    "z": 9.2
  }
]
```

How can I sort these two documents with 0.5(x) + 0.25(y) + 0.25(z)?

I tried doing

```
mydb.find().sort({0.5*x + 0.25*y + 0.25*z: 1})
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      w: {
        $add: [
          {$multiply: ["$x", 0.5]},
          {$multiply: ["$y", 0.25]},
          {$multiply: ["$z", 0.25]},
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$sort: {w: 1}},
  {$unset: "w"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wiPe-E86zXT)